# What are "disputed" flags?

Tags: support, flagging

The status  of some of my raised flags is "disputed":

> [image: screenshot of a disputed flag]

I know "helpful" means the flag *was* acted on, while "declined" means it *wasn't*.

What happened to "disputed" flags? What is a "dispute" in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A disputed flag is a flag that has been deemed invalid by a 10k+ user but not checked by a moderator yet. For more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277